# Add a datagridview to a dataset to visually control master-view?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two tables nested (master view) for representing my data. The parent table is called dtm below and the child table is dtd. I wanted to color some of the cells and after reading online it seemed that I needed to use something called a DataGridView. However, I am a little unsure how to modify what I currently have to utilise this DataGridView.

Could someone please help? I have omitted the tedious column and data insertion parts:

```
private DataTable CreateData()
{
    DataTable dtm = new DataTable();

    //Add the primary key first
    DataColumn dcmpk = dtm.Columns.Add();

    //Add the remaining columns
    dtm.Columns.Add();

    dtm.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dcmpk };

    //Add the data rows
    dtm.Rows.Add();

    //The table to be nested
    DataTable dtd = new DataTable();

    //Add foreign key first
    DataColumn dcdfk = dtd.Columns.Add();

    //Add the remaining columns for the child elements
    dtd.Columns.Add();

    //Add all the data for the child elements
    dtd.Rows.Add();


    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.AddRange(new DataTable[] { dtm, dtd });
    ds.Relations.Add("Relationship", dcmpk, dcdfk);
    return dtm;
}
```

This is what I have tried, but it was telling me Columns[0] was null:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.AddRange(new DataTable[] { dtm, dtd });
ds.Relations.Add("Relationship", dcmpk, dcdfk);
DataGridView dgv1 = new DataGridView();
dgv1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
dgv1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datasets and datatables are just data. they represent a subset of data from the database in memory. the data is represented as rows and columns.

to display the data to the user you need to bind the data in the dataset/table to UI controls. One type of user control is a DataGridView. there are plenty of introduction examples on the web on how to bind a dataset to a gridview.

Comment: call `dgv1.DataBind();` after setting the data source. this should fix it.

Comment: there doesn't appear to be a method named DataBind()?

Comment: sorry i'm thinking web not desktop. try explicitly setting `dgv1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;` before setting the datasource. if this doesn't work, I'm stumped.

Comment: Hi Jason, that didnt work either unfortunately :(

All the other examples I could find online were setting datasets or datatables to datagridviews, whereas I am doing the other way around.

Comment: Alternatively i would love to build my table using a DataGridView, but it didn't have the PrimaryKey property.... and I couldnt see how to add the DataGridView to the DataSet easilly for the relationship.

Comment: OK,that's the problem. a dataset is data the DGV is the presentation of the data. it's a one-way use. you cannot set a DGV to a dataset/table. think of it this way: you don't use a database to view a webpage, you view a webpage to see the data in the database. it's the same principle, just swap a dataset/table for a database.